# How to pass folder paths via a right-click event to visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, registry, contextmenu

[image: The image shows context menu item by mouse pointer]

I want to get path of folder to perform some action in visual studio (visual basic language). It is possible to copy path to clip board by following commands in registry.

```
cmd.exe /c (echo.|set /p=""%1"") | clip
```

But i need to copy to VB. If some one have an idea please suggest me.

Comment: Set the registry value to `C:\path\to\your\app.exe "%1"` and then read it from your application via [**`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(1)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How to store it to a string and call it in message box.

Comment: I literally just gave you the answer. All you have to do is set the latter to a string variable.

Comment: Your code worked properly. Thank you for your suggestions. In future, if I arise with some problem, I surely contact you.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck!